# Vim - how to pass argument to awk command

Tags: vim, awk

I have following simple csv file:

```
sno, name , age, gender
1 , abc, 30, M
2 , xyz, 60, F
3, def, 30, M
```

I want to use awk to find mean of a given column. I have tried following code:

```
command -nargs=1 Colmean %!awk -F',' '{ total += $<args>} END { print total/(NR-1)}'
```

to be used as follows:

```
:Colmean 3
```

However, the argument '3' is not being passed to awk command. Using double quotes instead of single quotes also does not work.

Where is the problem and how can it be solved? Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to do this from inside an editor instead of simply from the command line?

Comment: Maybe easier, analyze while seeing the file.

Comment: Using Excel or similar would be easier and clearer for that. Just sayin'....

Comment: Your command works perfectly for me. Did you try without plugin: `$ vim -Nu NONE`? Does your awk command work outside of Vim? Directly in Vim's command-line mode?

Comment: Yes, it works when ran with `-Nu NONE` options. What could be the cause? What kind of settings are likely to be resulting in this error?

Comment: Actually it started working after restarting. I am not sure why it was not working earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, you don't need awk here:

```
command! -range=% -nargs=1 ColMean echo eval(join(map(getline(<line1>,<line2>), 'split(v:val, ", ")[<args>]'), '+')) / (<line2>-<line1>+1.0)
```

Back to your question, command mappings may alter what you're really executing. You can try `:debug 2,$ColMean 3` on your buffer to see what's happening.